# Change Activity Theme From a Fragment

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-theme

I have a settings `PreferenceFragment` that allows the user to select a theme. The user can select a dark or light theme. After selecting a theme the user presses the back button to return to the previous fragment. This called the containing activity's onCreate method where the theme is read and applied. However the theme is not applied correctly, Switching from Holo.Light to Holo.Dark changes the background colour, action bar etc but does not change the text resulting in faded, hard to read text. Any ideas what I am doing wrong? Everything I have read says that the theme should be applied in the onCreate method and that is what I am doing.

Thanks in advance for your help.

**EDIT**

As requested here is the relevant code.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

     private ActionBarDrawerToggle mSlideMenuToggle;
     private boolean isDarkTheme;
     private static final String InitializedKey = "initialized";

     @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences, false);
          applySettings();
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       }

     @Override
     public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
          if (mSlideMenuToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
               return true;
          } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.menu_settings) {
               getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.content_frame, new SettingsFragment())
                        .addToBackStack(null)
                        .commit();
               return true;
          } else {
               return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
          }
     }

     private void applySettings() {
          isDarkTheme = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getString(SettingsFragment.ThemeSetting, null).equals("1");
          if (isDarkTheme) {
               setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Holo);
          } else {
               setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light);
     }
}
```

The `onCreate` method applies the current theme to the activity by calling `applySettings`. The options menu allows for a `SettingsFragment` to be created.

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

   public static final String ThemeSetting = "isDarkTheme";

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
   }

   @Override
   public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
       if (key.equals(ThemeSetting)) {
           String[] themes = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.isDarkThemeStrings);
           findPreference(key).setSummary(sharedPreferences.getString(key, "").equals("0") ? themes[0] : themes[1]);
       }
   }

   @Override
   public void onResume() {
       super.onResume();
       PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity()).registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
   }

   @Override
   public void onPause() {
       super.onPause();
       PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity()).unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
   }

 }
```

The `SettingsFragment` has one setting, Theme which can have one of two values, Dark or Light. The user picks one and then hits the back button. This causes the `onCreate` method of the `MainActivity` to be called, again applying the settings but not correctly.

Anyone? I feel like that once the theme is changed in the `SettingsFragment` and then the back button is pressed the theme should be applied to `MainActivity` but it is not. Most elements change but the text stays dark (going from Holo.Light to Holo.Dark).

Comment: More detail on what you've tried so far/code would help. Did you explicitly define your text to be changed. How did you do that?

Comment: I'm assuming that at one point you're finishing that activity(and you may want to use that `PreferenceFragment` in a `PreferenceActivity` instead of a normal one)? Also, the problem with the text is also for the `ActionBar` or just views(if you use any)?

Comment: @Luksprog The text issue is just the views. Currently I have only one activity and just replace parts of the layout with different fragments (ie. my `SettingsFragment`). So to answer your question, no I am not finishing the activity since it it really just there to hold my fragments. The `onCreate` method is called when leaving the `SettingsFragment` though so the theme is applied as if the activity was recreated. Right? Is this the wrong approach for preferences?

Comment: Make sure your views use the proper `Context` reference when they are created(which would be the context of the activity and not something like `getApplicationContext()`). I must admit that I don't understand how is the `onCreate()` called after you press back which should just pop the SettingsFragment(are you calling that by yourself). Preferences should be implemented in their own activity (`PreferenceActivity`).

Comment: Ensure you don't define the text color hardly with `R.color.white` or something like that.

Comment: @Luksprog thanks for the feedback, I will look and see if using a preferences activity along with the fragment makes a difference, I'm starting to think it might make more sense from the user point of view too. Just as an FYI I am using `getActivity` not `getApplicationContext` so I don't think that's it. Does Google say anywhere that a `PreferenceActivity` needs/should be used? My understanding was that most things should be done with `Fragments`?

Comment: @tbruyelle I am using the standard Holo.Light and Holo.Dark themes, I have no colours or styles defined at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I can help you with this.  I spent a lot of time over the last few months working on the exact same thing for my app.

The above poster isn't exactly correct.  You need to set the theme in `onCreate()` before views are instantiated -- before `setContentView()`.  When `super.onCreate()` is called isn't important.  I don't see `setContentView()` in your code above, so I'm wondering if you removed it?

However, if your activity is being themed correctly when you rotate (because it is destroyed and recreated on orientation change) then there's nothing wrong with how you're setting the theme.  Instead, I'm inclined to think you're mistaken about `onCreate()` being called when you exit the SettingsFragment.

You can force your activity to recreate itself like this:

```
finish();
startActivity(getIntent());
```

Please first try setting a breakpoint in your activity's `onCreate()` method and confirm whether it's hit on exiting your fragment (I bet it's not.)  Then try the code above.

Comment: I added where I call `setContentView` in my code above. If I call finish and launch a new activity then will I loose my back stack?

Comment: You are correct, `onCreate()` is not called when the back button gets pressed.

Comment: You can use the recreate() method of Activity class for recreation instead of finish() and startActivity(getIntent());

Answer (score 0):

Call `applySetting()` before super.onCreate().

If it's not working neither, answer this: when you set your preferences to dark style and close your app completely, when you open your activity, does your style is fine? ( check this with both `applySetting()` before and after `super.onCreate() )

Comment: as of right now, if you relaunch the app or rotate the app the theme is applied correctly, I will try calling `applySettings()` before `super.onCreate()` and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that unless you recreate the activity the theme will not be applied. Themes are applied to an activity prior to setContentView method call in onCreate(). When you navigate back you are not re-entering through the onCreate() method but through onResume().

To work around this issue, changing a theme preference will mean having to clear the back stack, otherwise the theme will not be applied to the activities in the back stack. From a usability point of view this sort of setting should only be available through the top level activities of your app anyway.

Implement a ThemeChangeListener and add it to your activities. When the theme changes, call the ThemeChangeListener and call finish() on any open activities (apart from the page you are in). Then in onBack() manually recreate the top level activity the user navigated to the settings page from using the code Lisa supplied.

You can use intent extras/data to manage re-creating the parent activity with the data previously populated.