# How to change theme of an app on runtime using onCreateView instead of onCreate

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-theme, appcompatactivity

So I have this code right now to change my app's theme -

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
public static int themeCheck = 0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (themeCheck == 1){
        setTheme(R.style.Dark);
    }
    else{
        setTheme(R.style.Light);
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_settings);
    }
    // some other code changing other stuff
```

I am working on this project with one more guy from my class, he was making the actual skeleton code, and turns out he used fragments and did not extend the activities to AppCompat. So, the class which I have to merge my code with looks something like this -

```
public class SettingsFrament extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment 
implements MainActivityFragment {
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = localInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings, 
    container, false);
    getActivity().setTitle(getString(R.string.settings_fragment_title));
    return rootView;

//This rootView and other bits that that guy gave me is redirecting the app 
//to my activity from the menu bar that he has.
```

I want to know how to merge my code with this class. (I don't HAVE to merge it, I can write the code down I just do not know how to use setTheme and other methods in onCreateView.)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `getActivity().setTheme()`?, and You have to restart the activity

Comment: also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17659413/change-activity-theme-from-a-fragment)

Answer (score 1):

Try this inside onCreateView callback.

```
    final Context theme1 = new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), R.style.yourCustomTheme1);
    final Context theme2 = new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(), R.style.yourCustomTheme2);

    LayoutInflater localInflater;

    getActivity().setTitle(getString(R.string.settings_fragment_title));

    if (themeCheck == 1){
         localInflater = inflater.cloneInContext(theme1);
    }
    else{
         localInflater = inflater.cloneInContext(theme2);
    }

    View rootView = localInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings,
            container, false);

    return rootView;
```